# Which is Right Way to Add Joystick in Unity3d , Adding on Scene Directly or Iniatiating it From Player Scripts

Tags: user-controls, unity-game-engine, game-development, joystick

I have to add Joystick control in my Game 
I had done with Two Approaches both works well for me , but confused Which one to go with.

1) Initiating Joystick Control from Players Object/Script and getting inputs there.
2) Add Joystick Control Directly to Game Scene and then accessing it in player script by findObjectwithTag and getting inputs .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling "Instantiate" and "GameObject.Find" is pretty expensive so in my opinion the efficient way is

1: Add Joystick Control Directly to Game Scene

2: Create a public object inside player and assign "joystick control" from inspector (Editor).

Comment: Is is a best practice to add it to game scene and Making object public, public object can be accessed by anyone.

What if I will Create a UserControl object and add JoyStick to it and then Add That  UserControl object to any Character Prefab  where i want joystick control, and access it by getComponentInChildren()
This way joystick control will remain private to character only.

Comment: Yup it is i think and always try to reduce the "Instantiate" and "GameObject.Find" calls. Public object is public inside your scene not out side the game :p and ya that's a good practice too means adding as a component :)

Comment: Thanks, 
When we say Joystick,it controls character's Actions, So this must be private to particular Character only.
I will go by adding joystick to character's Prefab as a subComponent.